# Carriage return in C?

Tags: c

Output of Following program is : `hai`

I didn't get how the `\r` carriage return works in this program and in real can any one help me out ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("\nab");
    printf("\bsi");
    printf("\rha");
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: [That's not the output I get](http://codepad.org/669KUYlv) (At least once I fix the `void main()`, and the nonstandard `conio.h` stuff.)

Comment: I'm using Visual C++ output is "hai"

Comment: if you put \n at the end of ab like 'ab\n' will get what you desire?

Comment: @Octopus: I don't think he *desires* any particular output, he wants to understand the cause of the output he is getting.  It is obviously just 'puzzle code' and of no practical use.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

From 5.2.2/2 (character display semantics) :

> **`\b`** (*backspace*) Moves the active
>   position to the previous position on
>   the current line. If the active
>   position is at the initial position of
>   a line, the behavior of the display
>   device is unspecified.
>
> **`\n`** (*new line*) Moves the active
>   position to the initial position of
>   the next line.
>
> **`\r`** (*carriage return*) Moves the active
>   position to the initial position of
>   the current line.

Here, your code produces :

- `<new_line>ab`
- `\b` : back one character
- write `si` : overrides the `b` with `s` (producing `asi` on the second line)
- `\r` : back at the beginning of the current line
- write `ha` : overrides the first two characters (producing `hai` on the second line)

In the end, the output is :

```
\nhai
```

Comment: @mr_eclair typo on the last line : fixed

Answer (score 15):

Program prints `ab`, goes back one character and prints `si` overwriting the `b` resulting `asi`.
Carriage return returns the caret to the first column of the current line. That means the `ha` will be printed over `as` and the result is `hai`

Answer (score 6):

Step-by-step:

[newline]ab

```
ab
```

[backspace]si

```
asi
```

[carriage-return]ha

```
hai
```

Carriage return, does not cause a newline.  Under some circumstances a single CR or LF may be translated to a CR-LF pair.  This is console and/or stream dependent.