# Writing multiline string with process.stdout in node

Tags: node.js, stream

I am trying to write a multiline string out to the console, but I am having issues. I thought I could use `\r` to go to a new line but it doesn't seem to be working, I end up with nothing displayed in the console.

I want to loop over an array of arrays and log each one out joined by a new line. I want to use `process.stdout.write` with `\r`'s rather than `\n`'s so I can go back and redraw the whole thing. I am fairly new to node so may be missing something obvious...

Example code:

```
this.grid.forEach((row) => {
  process.stdout.write(`${row.join(' ')}\r`);
});
```

If I omit the `\r` then I see the last line only

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7372938/5351549

Comment: Thanks, that helped :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript