# Why do I get this output when I use escape sequence?

Tags: c++, escaping

I try to study escape sequence so I am testing `\n`, `\r`, `\t` and I thought `\r` makes the cursor move to the beginning of the line.

I want to print:

```
hello
\r wokring      \t working \n working
```

so I enter this code in visual studio 2022

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "hello \n \\n working \r \\r working \t \\t working" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but it prints:

```
hello
\r_working       \t working
```

and a web compiler prints:

```
hello 
 \n working \r working   \t working
```

Why does this happen? Is there something I mistake about this?

Comment: `\r` is a carriage return, and means nothing special in *nix environments (afaik, which the Web environment probably is using). `\r` on Windows goes to the beginning of line, and will overwrite what is already written on that.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372918/whats-the-use-of-r-escape-sequence

Comment: Oh, sorry for asking duplicate questions without checking them properly

Comment: Instead of `\r` you could try `\033[G`.  For science.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `\r` is the carriage return (aka CR).
- `\n` is the new line character (aka LF / Line feed).
- Both characters are most often combined on Windows as `\r\n` (aka CRLF, that you can find e.g. in VBA through the `vbCRLF` constant).

That has historically always been a little bit of a mess as explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3720674/20143744).

We can work out your string to figure out what is going on:

```
hello \n \\n working \r \\r working \t \\t working
```

1. `Hello` is written, then it goes to the next line.
2. `\n working` is written, then it goes back to the start of the line.
3. `\r working`, then a `tab`, then `\t working` is written, but all of that overwrites `\n working` (since the cursor went back to the start of the same line).

I suspect your web compiler does not run on Windows (probably some Linux distribution), hence the different result.

Comment: Historically, the CR moves the carriage to the left margin.  The LF will advance the paper by one line (not adjusting the carriage location).  Thus to get to the left margin of the next line, two control characters would be issued:  CR, LF.  The 'nix programmers thought that was too many characters and elected to use LF to create their *Newline*.  Windows decided to keep the traditional Carriage Return Linefeed as their *Newline* combination.  It's history.  Try it out on a teletype or VT100 terminal emulator (I don't think finding the actual terminal is easy).